# Select input fields from html form in selenium

Tags: c#, unit-testing, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I want to select input fields from the following form in selenium. I have tried many methods but found no help and my test always fails. 
Here is the html form:

```
    `<form class="login" action="/Index/trylogin/?ru=L015RmlueWE=" novalidate>
        <fieldset>
            <label>
                <input type="text" maxlength="14" tabindex="1" value="" placeholder="Pseudonym">
            </label>

            <label>
                <input type="password" maxlength="20" tabindex="2" data-ch="8H7vtP9f9tns3TGMJ6F995kTyLSmwFsdDlIyBLhBBsrrW1ZHIZiec4cPqF7C5sp5" data-ch2="1782447a8c3759d4407ed522b831806e8cfde5dc" placeholder="Kennwort">
            </label>

            <input type="submit" value="Anmelden" class="button button-style1"> 

            <div class="login-options">
                <label>
                    <input type="checkbox" value="1" name="stayon">Automatisch anmelden (auf diesem Gerät)
                </label>
            </div>
        </fieldset>
    </form>`
```

Her is my test method

```
[TestMethod]
public void Login_FinYa_System()
{
    IWebElement login = _driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//form[1]"));
    IWebElement pass = _driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//form[2]"));
    login.Click();
    login.SendKeys("helo");
    pass.Click();
    pass.SendKeys("123");
    pass.SendKeys(Keys.Enter);
    Assert.AreEqual("hello", "hello");
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using incorrect xpath for login and password field.

**Try this.**

```
WebElement login = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@type='text']"));
WebElement password = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@type='password']"));
login.click();
login.sendKeys("hello");
pass.click();
pass.sendKeys("123");
pass.sendKeys(Keys.Enter);
Assert.assertEquals("hello", "hello");
```

Comment: Its not working I have tried it. here is another method I have tried `_driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//form[@class='login']/input[1]"))` it is not working as well

Comment: input is not direct child of form tag. Try this - //form[@class='login']//input[1‌​]

Comment: `Result Message: 
Test method Selenium_Testing.WikipediaSearchTest.Login_FinYa_System threw exception: 
OpenQA.Selenium.InvalidSelectorException: invalid selector: Unable to locate an element with the xpath expression //form[@class='login']//input[1‌​] because of the following error:
SyntaxError: Failed to execute 'evaluate' on 'Document': The string '//form[@class='login']//input[1‌​]' is not a valid XPath expression.
  (Session info: chrome=58.0.3029.81)`

Comment: Using this for login - //input[@type='text'] and use this for password //input[@type='password']

Comment: If you are not able to locate elements using this as well. Then focus must not be on frame on which elements are present. Then you have to switch to the frame first and then locate elements.

Comment: Try driver.switchTo().defaultContent() to switch to main frame then perform action.

Comment: `//input[@type='text']` and `//input[@type='password']` is working fine! thanks I will accept your answer

Comment: You can not accept two answers. You must accept one.